# Why Django makemigrations creates model, rename it to model_old, create again and delete the model_old?

Tags: django, django-migrations

After creating a Django model(using Python 3.5/Django 1.9.7/SQLite) with just few CharFields and a ForeignKey, running `manage.py makemigrations` I went to analyse the created SQL code with `manage.py sqlmigrate APP_NAME, MIGRATION_NAME` and got surprised with the result.

Can anyone explain why it is creating, renaming the table to model_old, creating again, importing the data from the created/rename model_old to the just created table and then deleting the model_old table?

I see the end result is looks correct with the table I really need, I'm just trying to understand why it is doing it. Bellow is the generated SQL script

```
BEGIN;
--
-- Create model Foo
--
CREATE TABLE "foo_foos" ("id" integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "created" datetime NOT NULL, "modified" datetime NOT NULL, "name" varchar(250) NOT NULL, "description" varchar(250) NOT NULL,"bar_id" integer NULL REFERENCES "foo_bar" ("id"));
--
-- Alter unique_together for foos (1 constraint(s))
--
ALTER TABLE "foo_foos" RENAME TO "foo_foos__old";
CREATE TABLE "foo_foos" ("id" integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "created" datetime NOT NULL, "modified" datetime NOT NULL, "name" varchar(250) NOT NULL, "description" varchar(250) NOT NULL,"bar_id" integer NULL REFERENCES "foo_bar" ("id"));;
INSERT INTO "foo_foos" ("created", "modified", "name", "description", "id", "bar_id") SELECT "created", "modified", "name", "description", "id", "bar_id" FROM "foo_foos__old";
DROP TABLE "foo_foos__old";
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX "foo_foos_name_42a88411_uniq" ON "foo_foos" ("name", "description");
CREATE INDEX "foo_foos_3b5ba656" ON "foo_foos" ("foo_id");

COMMIT;
```

And here is how the model looks like:

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_lenght=250)
    description = models.CharField(max_lenght=250)
    bar = models.ForeignKey(Bar, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('name', 'description')
```

Answer (score 0):

it's all about django emulation of SQLite, taken from the django official docs here's the explanation :

SQLite¶

SQLite has very little built-in schema alteration support, and so Django attempts to emulate it by:

```
Creating a new table with the new schema
Copying the data across
Dropping the old table
Renaming the new table to match the original name
```

This process generally works well, but it can be slow and occasionally buggy. It is not recommended that you run and migrate SQLite in a production environment unless you are very aware of the risks and its limitations; the support Django ships with is designed to allow developers to use SQLite on their local machines to develop less complex Django projects without the need for a full database